# Android: Taking picture and emailing it error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create an application to take a picture and then email it. I have spent the last few days messing around with my code and I have tried lots of different things and I still cant get it working. I can take a picture no problem its just when I go to send it my application crashes.Please see my code below:

```
public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton ib;
Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;
Bitmap bmp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo);
    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}

private void initialize() {
    ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibTakePic);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSendPic);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivReturnedPic);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bSendPic:
        String emailaddress[] = { "info@sklep.com", "", };

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);

        // getPackageName() is your app package
        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/ + R.drawable.ic_launcher");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path); // Replace your
                                                            // line
        emailIntent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));

        /*
         * emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
         * 
         * emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmp);
         * 
         * emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
         * startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));
         */

        break;
    case R.id.ibTakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
}
```

}

When I go to send it I get the following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND (has extras)
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you don't have any default app that supports email sending action. Did you check your phone for any such app?

Comment: Yeah I have already designed an app just to send normal emails but when I try and add a picture it doesnt work

Comment: You didn't take a picture. I think the issue is the attachment. Could you try this to initialize the Bitmap: `bmb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Comment: I tried that and it still crashes when I select gmail to send the email!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
startActivityForResult(((Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."))), 0);
```

Comment: I just tried that and and when I click send mail a dialog box pops up saying No applications can perform this action??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the appropriate app to handle this kind of intent.
Try instead to create chooser, this will open a dialog with the application that can deal with such intent.

Try to add the next lines:

use the next link: [getPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29)

```
//getPackageName() is your app package
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/ + R.drawable.ic_launcher");    
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path ); //Replace your line
            emailIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));
```

Comment: I tried this and this then gives me the option to select gmail but then it crashes once I select it!

Comment: The application Gmail(process com.google.adnroid.gm)has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Comment: I just tried that there and its still crashing. Is it really that tricky to take a picture and send it with android?Am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: I think the problem is that you trying to send image that is in your drawable folder. Try to save your image in the internal memory of the device and then send it. pay attention, you still need to use a Content Provider to take that picture from your app to the email app.

Comment: Tried that and still same error. I have updated my code above with your code. Did you mean to put uri instead of path at the end of emailIntent.putExtra?

Comment: Yeah its still crashing. Does it work on your phone? Maybe theres an issue with my phone?

Comment: @davemc I really don't know what to tell you, in my phone it works. look carefully if you write all the code above like it should.

Comment: What android version are you using? Im using 2.3.6

Comment: 3.2, but I don't think that is the problem. upload your code again please. maybe try to consider using a content provider.

Comment: I just restarted my laptop and phone and now I can send an email but it sends an email without the picture!

Comment: @davemc You need to use Content provider for the email app, can access and use your image app.

Answer (score 0):

Add 
      emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822"); before using `startActivity(emailIntent);`.
and use this also 
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

Comment: I tried that but Im still getting The application Gmail(process com.google.adnroid.gm)has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Comment: Then it seems you didnt configure any email application like email or anything else. first make sure you have configured any mail account.

Comment: I have configured my email account.I just sent a test email there from my phone and it works perfectly